# What numbers should A & B be?

Tags: pattern, dominoes

```
1  4  3  1  A 

2  2  6  4  B
```

What numbers should A & B be, with each vertical column being a domino tile.

Comment: Are the "numbers" A and B a single digit?

Comment: Single or double. In fact, each vertical column is a domino tile.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information for a unique solution here

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer could be

> $6$
>  $1$
>
>  This is the only domino tile (apart from 5-blank) which can make the same sum of each row:
>  $15$

Answer (score 1):

> $5$ $5$. Each number in the top row has it's successor somewhere in the bottom row.